# unable to delete products from a DIV tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a form in which there is a field where the user enters the **productName**.
 As the user enters the product name a list of products is shown to him via ajax with an **ADD button**. When the user clicks the add button, the **productName** is written into a `<div>` with a **delete button** with the help of jquery.
 Till here everything is working fine. Now I want that if the user clicks on the delete button then that product name is **removed from that particular** `<div> tag`. It works for the first time. But when i click the Delete button for next item. It is not working. Here is my **jquery code**

**CODE:**

```
$(function(){

$('.addProducts').keyup(function(event)
{
var searchVal=$(this).val().trim();
if(searchVal.length > 0)
{
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost/myurl',
data: {
products: $(this).val(),
},
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'html',
success: function(msg)
{
$('#printTheProducts').html(msg);
var productVal=$(this).attr('name');
var addedProductsValue=$('#myAddedProducts').html();
var textValueOfProducts=$('#myAddedProducts').text();
var deleteButton='<input type="button" class="deleteButton" value="Delete" name="'+productVal+'">';
if(textValueOfProducts.length===0)
{

$('#myAddedProducts').html(productVal+deleteButton);   
}
 else
{
var checkAddedProducts=textValueOfProducts.split(",");
if(checkAddedProducts.indexOf(productVal) < 0)
{
    $('#myAddedProducts').html(addedProductsValue+','+productVal+deleteButton);
}
 else
{
alert(productVal+' is already added');
}
 }
                            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code where I am Getting problem

$('.deleteButton').click(function()
{   
 var productsTextArray=new Array();
 var productsHtml;
var productsHtmlArray=new Array();
var deleteVal=$(this).attr('name');
 var myAddedProductsTextValue=$('#myAddedProducts').text().trim();
if(myAddedProductsTextValue.length > 0)
{
productsTextArray=myAddedProductsTextValue.split(",");
productsHtml=$('#myAddedProducts').html();
productsHtmlArray=productsHtml.split(",");

}
var deleteId=$.inArray(deleteVal,productsTextArray);
productsHtmlArray.splice(deleteId,1);
// if I add 
$('#myAddedProducts').html(productsHtmlArray.join());
then it prevents this function from working next time.I do not understand why

});
                            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
});

}
});
}
 }); 

    });
```

---

**Question**
How can I make this delete button to work for all the product name so that it can remove the name of that product from the `<div>`

Comment: would you please write your HTML code?

Comment: Because, you rewrite html, which was binded by `$('.deleteButton')` - you have to know about bindings

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand what your code is doing without a fiddle example to play with.

Is the click event being fired on the delete button the second time?

If not, then the problem is the event handler.

You can try this:  $('body').on('click', '.deleteButton', function(){
//put the code here.  replace 'body' with a  closer parent of the delete button for efficiency.
});
http://api.jquery.com/on/

If the click event is being fired, then perhaps the problem is here:

```
 var deleteVal=$(this).attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see you create one delete button for all your products,and assign it's name attribute to last added product.Because of that when you click your delete button it removes only last product.